# Join a count with Symfony2/Doctrine from another table?

Tags: orm, symfony, doctrine

I have some symfony/doctrine entity-classes and I want to add an count value joined from another table. Is it possible to configure it per annotations? The pseudo class is just an example to point out what I need.

```
class Person {

    protected $id;

    /**
     * SELECT COUNT(id) FROM children WHERE parent_id=$this->id
     */
    protected $countChildren;
}
```

I need just that value and in that case I use it. There is not a closer relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you would have a 1:n relation in a well-formed sql database because cleary one child belongs to one parent. I assume one parent can have multiple children.

If you have that relation, you can simply count the childrens ArrayCollection. If not, you may have to write a dql query in the repostiory and provide the parent id.

I don't know any way of doing this with annotations.